# Get the Date of Months Week Number

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, date

I have a code `2014P07W4` which means:

`2014` = year

`P07` = 7th month of the year

`W4` = 4th week of the month.

I would like to work out the date of the First day of the 4th week in July 2014. In this example I would expect to see a date of 21/7/2014.

July 2014 weeks

- Week 1 - 1st to 6th
- Week 2 - 7th to 13th
- Week 3 - 14th to 20th
- Week 4 - 21st to 27th
- Week 5 - 28th to 31st

From the code I know the week no = 4 then I want to be able to calculate the date 21/7/2014. I am assuming the first day of the week is a Monday

I am asking how to read that code and get the first day of the week specified

Hope this is clearer it has been a long day

Comment: What exactly defines a week of the month?  Is it just seven-day blocks or does it relate to a day of the week or the like?  If it's the former then isn't 21/7/2014 the last day of the third week?  Also, what actually is the question here?  Can you restate is CLEARLY?  Are you asking us how to read that code and get the first day of the week specified?  If so then actually ask that.

Comment: The question was "..get the first day of the week specified", while "I am assuming the first day of the week is a Monday". I see confusion here, because Week 1 doesn't start from Monday. So what is a correct result for 2014P07W1? Put more examples for better understanding the specification of such date code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to parse the code and extract the year, month, and weekNo an numbers. 
Then, you can use this method to get the start day of the week:

```
int WeekStartDay(int year, int month, int weekNo)
{
    DateTime monthStart = new DateTime(year, month, 1);

    int monthStart_DayOfWeek = ((int)monthStart.DayOfWeek + 6) % 7;

    int weekStart_DayOfMonth = 1;
    if (1 < weekNo) {
        weekStart_DayOfMonth += 7 - monthStart_DayOfWeek;
    }
    if (2 < weekNo) {
        weekStart_DayOfMonth += 7 * (weekNo - 2);
    }
    return weekStart_DayOfMonth;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take first day of month (2014/07/01), find next Monday (first day of 2nd week), add 14 days (first day of 4th week).

```
DateTime date = new DateTime(2014, 7, 1);
int daysToFirstDayOf2ndWeek = date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday
                              ? 7
                              : ((int)DayOfWeek.Monday - (int)date.DayOfWeek + 7) % 7;
DateTime firstDayOf2ndWeek = date.AddDays(daysToFirstDayOf2ndWeek);
DateTime firstDayOf4thWeek = firstDayOf2ndWeek.AddDays(14);
```

Answer (score 0):

may be this will works

```
    string code = "2014P07W4";
    int yr = int.Parse(code.Substring(0, 4));
    int mnth = int.Parse(code.Substring(5, 2));
    int week = int.Parse(code.Substring(8));

    DateTime dt = new DateTime(yr, mnth, 1);
    if (dt.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday)
    {
        DateTime newdate = dt.AddDays((week - 1) * 7);
    }
    else
    {
        DateTime newdate = dt.AddDays((8 - (int)dt.DayOfWeek) % 7 + ((week - 2) * 7));
    }
```